# How MIPS assembler acquires immediate (CONSTANT) values?

Tags: assembly, mips

I couldn't find similar question anywhere.
For example when we want to add a predefined value in memory we get its address and copy its content but if we want to add 40000 to a register how assembler interprets 40000 and copies its value.
Thank you if help me understand this concept

Comment: This is something you can easily experiment on and find out for yourself.  Use the easy to use MARS simulator, and type `li $t0, 40000`, then look at the generated machine code and disassembly.  You can even try different values to see what happens!!

Comment: 32 bit fixed length instructions do not have room for 32 bit immediates so the architecture has to solve that problem, mips solved it by having ways to set the upper 16 bits to an immediate and the lower to zeros, and then a number of others that can have 16 bit immediates that can be used to set/modify the lower 16 bits.  Combine two of them and you can create any bit pattern.  if your immediate/constant has all zeros for the upper or lower 16 bits then it can be done with one instruction.

Comment: some instruction sets will load a constant with a pc-relative load, others are variable length and the whole constant is part of the instruction.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks for your help. Actually I meant how these bits are generated and I think I got my answer that keyboard produces each bit and stores it in memory I don't know it's true or not

Comment: This last comment and my selected answer dont make sense together.  If you are asking how a keyboard and computer and operating system and text editor all work together that is one thing and has nothing to do with MIPS or assembly language or machine code or anything like that.  If this is a machine code question that connects to an assembly language, then the selected answer demonstrates the instructions.

Comment: @old_timer actually you're right I misunderstood that keyboard may produce bits for a value and not just assembler is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int fun0 ( void )
{
    return 40000;
}
unsigned int fun1 ( void )
{
    return 0x40000;
}
unsigned int fun2 ( void )
{
    return 0x12345678;
}
unsigned int fun3 ( void )
{
    return 0x12340000;
}
unsigned int fun4 ( void )
{
    return 0x00005678;
}

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   03e00008    jr  $31
   4:   34029c40    li  $2,0x9c40 ; 0x34xxxxxx ORI $2,$0,0x9c40

00000008 <fun1>:
   8:   03e00008    jr  $31
   c:   3c020004    lui $2,0x4

00000010 <fun2>:
  10:   3c021234    lui $2,0x1234
  14:   03e00008    jr  $31
  18:   24425678    addiu   $2,$2,22136

0000001c <fun3>:
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   3c021234    lui $2,0x1234

00000024 <fun4>:
  24:   03e00008    jr  $31
  28:   24025678    li  $2,22136  ; 0x24xxxxxx  ADDIU $2,$0,0x5678


unsigned int fun5 ( void )
{
    return 0x9999;
}
00000000 <fun5>:
   0:   03e00008    jr  $31
   4:   34029999    li  $2,0x9999  ; 0x34xxxxxx  ORI $2,$0,0x9999
```

li is a pseudo instruction.

Comment: Unfortunately that disassembly doesn't distinguish between `ori` with `$zero` for 0..65535 values vs. `addiu` for -32768 .. 32767 values.  It's just showing them as `li`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes compiler produced li, assembler chose addiu for one when it could just use ori for both cases, and then disassembler chose to show li instead of the real instruction.

Comment: Yes I understand how and why you got this output from the tools.  I see you understood my real point that saying something about how `li` was implemented as a single instruction would make it a better answer, since you added that. :)

Comment: My implied point is that it takes about the same time to just have a/some tool show you in roughly the same time it takes to create an SO question...I knew it would be doing an add or or, but didnt think to change the li at the time.

Answer (score 2):

The value is encoded directly into the instruction word.

For example, the instruction `ADDI rs,rt,immediate` has the following encoding:

```
         001000   rs   rt  immediate
#bits:     6       5    5      16
```

So the immediate constant would be placed in the 16 least-significant bits of the instruction word. Note that the immediate is sign-extended, so it can only encode values in the range -32768..+32767. So you can't add 40000 to a register with a single instruction, unless you already happen to have the value 40000 in some register.

For more information, see the document *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*.